# display unicode in Html Widget of iPyWidgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, jupyter, ipywidgets

I want to show Unicode text (Persian text) in Jupiter. Currently, I use from HTML widget to show the text likes the following:

```
# title is unicode
title_value = widgets.HTML(value = title)
```

But, I've gotten the following error:

> TraitError: Could not decode '\xd9\xbe\xda\x98\xd9\x88 405 \xd9\x85\xd8\xb4\xda\xa9\xdb\x8c \xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd9\x88\xd8\xb4 90 91' for unicode trait 'value' of a HTML instance.

Anyhow, when `print` the title the result would be in Persian.
What supposed to resolve the issue?

I should have mentioned that `encode("utf-8")` does not work properly, as I want to show the Unicode text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution which I found is using `decode("utf-8")`:

```
title_value = widgets.HTML(value = title.decode("utf-8"))
```